# Как на основе Expression<Func<T, bool>> скомпоновать URL

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования, lambda, репозиторий, ddd

Разрабатываю приложение, пытаюсь в нём следовать "чистой архитектуре" Роберта Мартина. Начал со слоя данных, добрался до проектирования удаленного источника данных, в нем имею такого рода код:

```
public override async Task<IList<Entity>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> expression = null)
    {

    }
```

где Expression это по сути "спецификация"
т.е. обычный непримечательный код где на входе мы задаем лямбдой условие для выборки Entity, такой подход прекрасно работает для локального источника данных (БД), потому что скомпилированный Expression мы можем скормить DbContext-у, а дальше уже происходит EF-магия без нашего участия. Но вот проблема с внешним источником данных, в моем случае я должен в зависимости от Expression скомпоновать URL чтобы получить свои entities по условию, и что то я не могу придумать как это сделать, и пока не удается нагуглить какие есть инструменты для этого. Что можете посоветовать?

UPD
Expression на входе:

```
 var res = await remoteDataSource.GetAsync(z=> z.Address == EntityPlace.Moscow);
```

(для примера считайте что Address это строка)

То что хочу получить:

```
 //В классе источнике данных
 private static string UrlAddress = @"https://moi.address/?";
 private const string UrlPlaceFilter = @"s%5Bplace%5D%5B0%5D=";
 private List<string> UrlPlaces = new List<string>()
 {
        "Moscow",
        "London",
        "Paris"
 };

public override async Task<IList<Entity>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> expression = null)
{
    //z=> z.Address == EntityPlace.Moscow
    //на основе этого условия нам нужна строка URL
    //https://moi.address/?s%5Bplace%5D%5B%5D=Moscow

}
```

Comment: Приведите пример Expression на входе и что вы хотите получить на выходе из него

Comment: @АндрейNOP будьте добры, посмотрите обновления в посту

Comment: Вам придется писать разбор Expression вручную, а вариантов там может быть уйма, начиная от `MemberExpression` до всевозможных конфигураций с `BinaryExpression` вложенных друг в друга, каждое из которых может быть опять таки `BinaryExpression` (`BinaryExpression` здесь могут получаться от операций `&`, `&&`, `|`, `||`) и процентов 90 из них будет невозможно представить в виде валидного `uri`-запроса. Поэтому, как мне кажется, овчинка здесь не стоит выделки. Проще написать кучку методов с фиксированными параметрами-фильтрами

Comment: Можно, конечно, ограничить входное выражение до простого `==` где левая часть — строго доступ к члену класса, а правая — строго константа или выражение вычисляемое на клиентской стороне, а на всё остальное падать с ошибкой. Ну тогда задача значительно упростится, берете у входного параметра `var body (BinaryExpression)expression.Body`, потом из `var member = (MemberExpression)body.Left` извлекаете `member.Member` и оттуда название свойства (или название из атрибута к этому свойству)

Comment: А правую часть компилируете и выполняете чтоб получить константное значение для запроса. Это будет примерно так: `var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(body.Right); var value = lambda.Compile()();` (да, две пары скобок), потом форматируете в нужный вид (я бы с помощью того же атрибута передавал бы еще и формат) и приклеиваете к uri

Comment: @АндрейNOP Не кастуется к Binary, Message: System.InvalidCastException: Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpressionN" к типу "System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression".

Comment: Покажите какое выражение передали. Судя по всему у вас не `==`, а вызов метода

Comment: @АндрейNOP ага, было equals, переделал на ==, теперь вижу. Правильно я понимаю что мне нужен собственный LINQ провайдер чтобы поддерживать expressionы?

Comment: Да, как я и говорил выше, там очень много вариантов может быть на входе. Вам придется или жестко ограничить допустимые, либо написать набор методов с фиксированными параметрами. Ну или писать полный разбор, что тянет уже на неплохую библиотеку (кстати, может быть такие библиотеки уже существуют?)

Comment: @АндрейNOP Ну фильтров у меня не так много - дата, место плюс/минус еще пара, думаю возни много не возникнет, зато получу опыт.

Comment: У вас url с одним прараметром, у которого 3 возможных значения. Зачем вам для этого городить всю эту ерунду с выражениями? Я не припомню рекомендацию от Мартина писать тяжелый непонятный код для 1 параметра с 3 значениями. Делайте спокойно метод с 1 строковым (или enum) параметром и подставляйте его в URL и не выдумывайте ерунды.

Comment: @tym32167 вы же понимаете что код в моём примере это именно пример а не реальная задача? Реальный Url содержит в себе куда больше параметров - дата, место, категория, цена от-до итд. Что же касается Мартина - то он рекомендует использовать один интерфейс для работы с источниками данных - т.е. всеравно какой это источник - база, рест-апи, интерфейс доступа к данным должен быть один и тот же, что я и пытаюсь сделать.

Comment: Ну так пусть будет метод с нужным количеством параметров, вы его и для бд можете использовать, и для построения урла. Это вроде не противоречит Мартину. Да и, честно говоря, сам Мартин не всегда дает хорошие советы, потому я бы им слепо не стал следовать. Он, насколько я помню, больше с++ занимался, сам недавно чистый код читал, такое себе чтиво. Я бы вам посоветовал думать своей головой. Вот какая вам будет польза непосредственно от того, что вы разберете выражение? Я такой необходимости не вижу, и пользы тоже, вижу только усложнение кода, увеличение времени разработки и тяжесть поддержки.